# is it possible to calculate next z-index in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, z-index

Is it possible to get the highest z-index property in some container if none of the elements in it have z-index set via styles? The only approach i've found googling returns "auto" for the z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [JQuery Module](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TopZIndex) that can do this.

Comment: It seems this JQuery module treats 'auto' as 0. Wonder if that's a good solution...

Comment: Seems reasonable according to my reading of http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index

Answer (score 0):

If no z-index is set then auto is the z-index...

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so without specifically scripting a solution - i've always wanted something like `getNextHighestDepth` which you get in Actionscript